# How to distinguish http and https by http-header

Tags: c#, ssl, proxy, http-headers, tcplistener

I am writing a proxy with `TcpListener` in C#.

This proxy listens a port that users send request to. And when accepted a user request, it will parse the request header and find the host name. Then it creates a `TcpClient` to the host server.

Here comes the problem. When http request comes, it should connect the port 80 of the server; while https request comes, it should connect the port 443 of the server. But I have no idea of how to distinguish http request and https request.

Question in one sentence: how to know it is a http request or https request that `TcpListener` accepted?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've stepped in a problem that has flustered web server administrators for a long time.

Here's the process:

1. Web browser establishes a TCP connection to a particular IP on the web server.
2. The web server knows what IP it's getting a connection from, knows that that IP is only ever used for secure.example.com, and so loads the SSL certificate for secure.example.com.
3. The web server and web browser negotiate a SSL connection.
4. The web browser sends vanilla HTTP headers down the SSL pipe, which include the "HOST: secure.example.com" line that indicates the virtual host to use.
5. The web server processes the request and sends the response using vanilla HTTP headers sent down the SSL pipe.

The web server has to decide which virtual host to use before it has any HTTP headers. This is because it has to negotiate an SSL connection first, and it has to know which certificate to use first. The vanilla solution is to use IP-based virtual hosts - run the web server on IP address X; whenever the server gets a request sent to address X, it knows the request belongs to the configured vhost for that address.

The problem with that scheme is that the server has to have separate IP addresses for each secure website it runs. That might be many, many IP addresses, and is either costly or impractical.

Step in [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). When the web browser is negotiating the SSL connection to the web server, the web browser includes the hostname it wants to connect to in the SSL negotiation information. Now the web server can use that information to do normal name-based virtual hosts, and so the web server can run a thousand different secure websites each with their own SSL certificates all on exactly one IP address. Everything is right in the world again.

You want to get in the middle of this, which means that you have to understand the SSL/TLS negotiation phase, parse the server name information, and forward the request down to the right web server.

Your new flow looks something like this:

1. Web browser establishes a TCP connection to the proxy.
2. Proxy begins recording the SSL exchange.
3. Web browser starts to do SSL negotiation, and as part of such, sends the Server Name Information down.
4. The proxy parses the Server Name Information, decides which web server should handle the request, and forwards the SSL negotiation information to the web server.
5. The proxy does not otherwise participate in the negotiation; it reads the SNI, but otherwise is completely "pass-through".
6. The web browser and server complete the SSL negotiation, the server picks the right vhost, and the browser sends vanilla http headers for a request.
7. The web server reads the vanilla headers via the SSL connection, and processes the request.

Now that that's been said, you might realize that sticking your nose in the SSL connection negotiation might be more trouble than it's worth. Turns out a few other people have already had the same idea as you and have implemented a few programs that seem to do exactly what you're trying to do - do a search for "http sni proxy" - I came up with this: https://github.com/dlundquist/sniproxy

Answer (score 0):

The headers are entirely encrypted. The only information going over the network 'in the clear' is related to the SSL setup and D/H key exchange. This exchange is carefully designed not to yield any useful information to eavesdroppers, and once it has taken place, all data is encrypted.

**Update** By the way After the SSL negotiation, normal HTTP headers will travel inside the encrypted stream, so there is really no difference between the two.

Comment: You mean it is impossible?

Comment: I just want to transit ssl stream between server and user, not to decrypt the content, is there a method?

Comment: HTTPS is an abbreviation for HTTP over TLS/SSL. as i told before you can just get information before SSL negotiation

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? because as far as i know you https is just http over ssl.